# Are there any animation tools available to visualise and simulate deep neural networks?

Tags: deep-learning, deep-neural-networks, models, software-evaluation, topology

Deep learning researchers have to work with a lot of models. The models may include different types of Layers: They include convolutional neural network layers, recurrent neural network layers, batch normalization layers, polling layers, and many others.

Along With their own visualization, it is also necessary to keep the model detailed enough visually to teach about the model.

Although there are widely used visualization methods available in several packages such as [model summary](https://keras.io/api/models/model/#summary-method) and others. I want to know the availability of animation tools that are useful to simulate the models of deep learning that are more visually intuitive.

Are there any contemporary animation packages available true to draw and simulate deep learning models?

Comment: Asking for "tools" or "software libraries" is off-topic here, so this question seems to be off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you take a look at [Chris Olah's blog](https://colah.github.io/). Has several interesting post including ones on [visualizing weights](https://distill.pub/2020/circuits/visualizing-weights/) and [interpretability](https://distill.pub/2018/building-blocks/). Most of his papers also have Google Colab links so you can reproduce the results.

If you want something more similar to the `model.summary()` method you mention, [TensorBoard Graph Dashboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/graphs) might help.